# Calculate fft for each column or row in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, fft

I have a problem with calculating fft for a signal which is stored in a matrix using matlab. I am trying to calculate fft for each column.

I am trying to do this like this:

```
 for k = 1: ncol
    y1(k)= fft(y(:,k));
 end
```

where `y` is my matrix and and `ncol` is number of columns in matrix but I'm still getting the following error:

> ```
> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this

```
y1 = fft(y);
```

It computes each column separately and it does it much faster than using a for loop.

In response to your original question, you would have to do it like this:

```
 for k = 1: ncol
    y1(:,k)= fft(y(:,k));
 end
```

You were trying to put an entire column into a single index which is why you were getting that error message. You need to allocate more room so that the entire column can be stored.

Comment: It is also worth nothing that `fft` also takes an optional argument to explicitly specify the dimension along which the FFT is computer. So `fft(y,[],1)` computes each column separately, and `fft(y,[],2)` computes each row separately.

Answer (score 0):

y1 should also be in matrix form. fft of a signal is an array of coefficients